# Einstein's overdetermination theory

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, einstein

In 1923 [[1]](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol14-trans/193), Einstein proposed an idea for a classical theory that would explain some features of quantum mechanics, via the overdetermination of the EoM, so that only certain configurations would be available as initial values. He did not expand much on the idea or offered much in the way of examples.

As far as I can tell [[2]](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=13498575195552129215&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en), this idea seemed to have no follow up, and this paper only seems to be cited in papers on the history of Einstein , no responses, rebuttal, or any other comments.

Was there ever any development on this idea, or did it die right there in this first paper?